# Column matrices using nicematrix do not display properly

Tags: nicematrix

`nicematrix` seems not to display column matrices correctly. Is there a way to fix this, so that one doesn't have to change all files to use `NiceArray`? I also use `[renew-dots,renew-matrix]`, so that matrices typeset using the `amsmath` matrix environments benefit from `\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 1pt}`. (I haven't used `[renew-dots,renew-matrix]` here to show the difference between `nicematrix` and `amsmath`.) As a result, unfortunately, I can't remove the `[renew-dots,renew-matrix]` option and just use `pmatrix`. (As you can see below, the rows in matrices using `pmatrix` are too close.)

I'm not sure if `nicematrix` always did this. I think I would have noticed, but maybe I didn't. Observe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{nicematrix} 

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 1pt}

\begin{document}
        
NiceMatrix

\begin{align*}
        v_1 &= 
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
                1\\
                0 \\3 \\
                4\\5 
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
        \\
        v_2 &= 
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}
                0\\
                1 
        \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}

NiceArray

\begin{align*}
        v_3 &= \left(
        \begin{NiceArray}
                {c} \frac{1}{2} \\
                \frac{1}{4} 
        \end{NiceArray}
        \right) \\
        v_4 &= \left(
        \begin{NiceArray}
                {c} 1 \\
                0 
        \end{NiceArray}
        \right) 
\end{align*}

Without nicematrix

\begin{align*}
        v_5 &= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
                a\\
                b \\c \\
                d 
        \end{pmatrix}
        \\
        v_6 &= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
                \frac{1}{2} \\
                \frac{1}{4} 
        \end{pmatrix}
        \\
        v_7 &= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
                \frac{1}{2} & 1\\
                \frac{1}{4} & 2 
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: various types of column matrices]

**EDIT:** I'm using version 6.26a of `nicematrix`, dated 2023-12-04.

Comment: I actually get exactly the opposite: the NiceMatrix version looks good, the NiceArray version does not. I was able to fix the latter by putting "cc" in the argument rather than just "c"; I'm not sure what the cause of that problem is.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. I wonder which version of nicematrix you are using. I'm using 6.26a, (which should be the latest one.)

Comment: I am using 6.16 (comes with TeXLIVE 2023). I am unable to use 6.26a, as it relies on `\int_if_zero:nT` (which is evidently a new feature of the LaTeX3 kernel since February 2023).

Comment: Interesting... Thanks! What does `\int_if_zero:nT` do? Anyway, it suggests to me that this is new behavior.

Comment: I also get correct spacing with `pNiceMatrix` and `bNiceMatrix`. Spacing on `NiceArray` is fixed by using `pNiceArray` instead of `\left(` and `\right)`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning pNiceArray! That will save me some typing if I have to convert. Like I asked karlh, which version of `nicematrix` are you using?

Comment: This is bug in the latest version of `nicematrix`. I will post a new version on CTAN.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Thank you!

Comment: @F.Pantigny By the way, I love `nicematrix`!

Comment: @F.Pantigny I just received the updated version through TeXLive. It works! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.26b 2023-12-13) solves that bug.